# Why do people answer questions when the OP has already accepted an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

I just got a notification that someone had added an answer to a several year old question which I had already accepted an answer for. It didn't require any additional answers. Should the OP not be able to close the question of further answers when they are happy with the answer?

Comment: And you can be 100% the answer is perfect and correct for all eternity? I don't think so.

Comment: Remember: the original author of the question is just **one of many** people who gain something from the answers. Most questions have many, many views. That means that many *other* people are searching for answers for that (or similar) questions. And *they* might require slightly different answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the OP should not be able to prevent further answers.

The primary purpose of a Stack Exchange site is to build an excellent documentation resource in question-answer form. (See the about page for any Stack Exchange site; for example, [the one for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/about). "With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.") Even if the OP is right to think future answers won't help them--and it would be difficult to really know this!--they may help others.

Questions are about their authors. But they're more about the community at large, and they're *even more* about the documentation-creating project that the community is collaborating on. For the same reason people besides the OP should be able to *see* questions and answers, so too should it be possible to add new answers.

Accepting an answer serves the purpose of indicating that it solved the OP's problem according to the OP. That's its sole purpose. Whether or not a question has an accepted answer doesn't say anything about whether or not further answers would be helpful.

Furthermore, additional answers even after an answer has been accepted frequently help the OP too. They may present alternative solutions, or better versions of solutions that have already been posted.

Answer (score 26):

Questions should not be closed just because there is an accepted an answer to it.

*Most* questions have multiple solutions and since technology is constantly changing, it is possible that there is a new way to solve the problem that will help others in the future.

The StackExchange sites are open to anyone and while one person asked the question the solution is not just limited to the original poster. The question and answers are supposed to be a reference point for the community to use so we want to build the best reference possible and limiting that to one answer defeats the purpose.

The acceptance checkmark shows that the OP found the answer that solved their problem, that doesn't mean that other answer cannot or should not be added.

I can say from my own experience, if I find a question that has an alternate solution to the accepted one, I will post it because it might help someone else.

Comment: I've also seen plenty of accepted answers that couldn't possibly solve the OP's problem because they're horribly wrong but were apparently accepted without trying them out.

Comment: @Wooble That is very true, I see that a lot. Where the OP accepts the answer and it is incorrect. If the questions were closed then a correct answer would not be allowed to be posted.

Comment: Stop all that jibba jabba. As if there would ever be a new/better way to do something in IT.

Comment: @swasheck You are right, I have no idea what you are talking about... _Wait, where is my blackberry...nope my iPhone...Oops my Android phone_ I can't remember what tech I use anymore.

Answer (score 7):

possible reason could be  they think they provide better information than answer already given

and in case if you found other answer is exact duplicate fo other you can flag it with other option

and because op accepted answer that doesn't mean that other answer cannot/should not be added since its possible that later answer could be more informative

Comment: Or, possibly simply an alternative. Not necessarily better. =D